docker-compose container not reachable by external network
NOTE: I switched to SF:   https://serverfault.com/questions/1168586/docker-compose-container-not-reachable-by-external-network-port-is-filtered
I have set up a docker container on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to be accessible by port 8457.
But I can't connect to the container from external.
version: '3'
services:

    t32tcpusb_3-6:
        image: ubuntu
        command: /home/fileuser/t32/bin/pc_linux64/t32tcpusb
        privileged: true
        stop_grace_period: 2s

        volumes:
          - "/home/fileuser/t32:/home/fileuser/t32"
          - "/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6:/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6"

        devices:
          - "/dev/lauterbach/trace32/3-6"

        ports:
          - "8457:8455"


Connecting from localhost is working.
SSH-Tunnel to localhost is working.
Connecting via Host-IP fails as timeout.

If I run the application outside of the container:
$ sudo nmap -sS -p8455 192.168.1.104
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8455/tcp open   unknown

If I run the application inside of the docker
$ sudo nmap -sS -p8457 192.168.1.104
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8457/tcp filtered unknown

And the docker-proxy is also running fine:
$ ps aux|grep docker-proxy
root        9293  0.0  0.0 1745360 3668 ?        Sl   22:37   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8457 -container-ip 172.22.0.2 -container-port 8455
root        9300  0.0  0.0 1745360 3700 ?        Sl   22:37   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 8457 -container-ip 172.22.0.2 -container-port 8455

Do you have any idea what is causing the docker-related ports to be filtered?
What is also confusing: This setup was working fine several months, and just now I discovered it failing..
NOTE: I switched to SF:  https://serverfault.com/questions/1168586/docker-compose-container-not-reachable-by-external-network-port-is-filtered

I'd suggest removing the expose configuration. See What is the difference between ports and expose in docker-compose?

Your descriptions don't make a lot of sense. You say you tried 8455 "outside" of the container and 8457 "inside" but you've mapped host port 8457 to container port 8455

@Phil, I tried both with and without expose. But I'll keep expose out then. With 8455 outside I mean that I ran the application without docker - natively it uses port 8455. This way I tested if nmap would show "open".

At this stage I'd suspect your firewall. Docker Compose by default binds ports to the host 0.0.0.0 address so it should work. There's some discussion on a similar topic here ~ https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/msgbzo/cant_connect_to_docker_container_over_lan_only/. You might get better traction on this question at https://serverfault.com/

@Phil thx for your help, switched to SF, will update here when I got something
